# Windows Phone 7 SIP keyboard color

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am planning to have an app that is using the light scheme regardless of what the system wide color scheme.

Is it possible to change the color scheme of the SIP keyboard to light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default SIP keyboard, you can't.

But you can create a custom keyboard. 
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx

Comment: very useful tip and article. I read it and I am not sure I am ready to create my own keyboard. I think this would be an overkill for me :)